# What options are available to add a calculated attribute to Mage_Core_Model_Product?

Tags: product, overrides, custom, core, extend

We've got a number of attributes which are generated by basic Excel formulas and then bulk-loaded into the catalog via imports.  The process results in "extra" attributes which are read-only and shouldn't be altered by individuals.

Ideally these values wouldn't be stored in EAV attributes, but would instead be calculated on-the-fly as needed.  I've considered (and not ruled out) extending the `catalog/product` model to have additional methods for this data, such as:

```
class My_Extension_Model_Catalog_Product extends Mage_Core_Catalog_Product {

  public function getSomeValue() {

    if (!$x = $this->getX() || !$y = $this->getY()) {
      return null;
    }

    return ($x * $y);
  }
}
```

The attribute needs to be available to consumers who expect it to behave like any other attribute--they should be able to call `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(123)->getSomeValue();` without any extra boilerplate or bootstrapping.

What other options would I have?  Would there be events that would let me calculate and set the value when the product is being loaded?  Or better could I assign the function when the product is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fixed amount of attributes I would suggest to implement a custom extension that creates them using the install script. The calculation can be done by rewriting the Mage_Core_Catalog_Product like you've written above.

As for as events goes you have 2 events for loading products:

1. **catalog_product_load_before**
2. **catalog_product_load_after**.

For loading product collections you have

1. **catalog_product_collection_load_before**
2. **catalog_product_collection_load_after**.

Comment: I'll see if I can build a solution into the collection load events; if possible I'd like to keep the data out of the database

Comment: At event `catalog_product_load_after` you can inject data into the model `$model->setData('custom_attribute', $x * $y)`, then it will be available both as `$model->getData('custom_attribute')` and `$model->getCustomAttribute();`